# Rename output file in the new Android Plugin 3.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I was using this in the previous gradle plugin and it was working fine.

```
applicationVariants.all { v ->
v.outputs.each { output ->
    output.outputFile = new File(
            output.outputFile.parent,
            output.outputFile.name.replace("app-release.apk", "companyName-app-v${variant.versionName}.apk"))
}}
```

With the recent update to 3.0.0-alpha1 it shows error.

I read the link https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html but was unable to find the exact source of error.

Is there a fix to this I am missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To change the APK name, you can change it to:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "companyName-app-v${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

> If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects, you need to
>   start using all(). That's because each() iterates through only the
>   objects that already exist during configuration time — but those
>   object don't exist at configuration time with the new model. However,
>   all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are added
>   during execution.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output)

Comment: Even though this is what the official documentation says to do, it doesn't work.

Comment: Looking closer variant.outputs returns a Collection of type com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariantOutput, and not a DefaultDomainObjectCollection so the all closure cannot be applied to it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Canary 3, and this is working for me.  But see the kludge for the ABI name?  I couldn't figure out where to get the ABI in the new structure, so extracted it from the default name (sucks).  If anyone knows a better way to get the ABI name when using splits (to change the versionCode per ABI), I'd love to hear.  Maybe its time to post a separate question. Anyway, this works on prod APK builds.

```
def ext = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")
ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'x86': 8]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name != "debug") {
        variant.outputs.all { vOutput ->
            // there has got to be a better way to get the ABI name than this kludge
            def nameTokens = vOutput.name.split("-");
            def abiName = nameTokens[1]
            abiName = nameTokens[2].contains("v7a") ? abiName + "-v7a" : abiName
            def versionNumber = ext.versionCodes.get(abiName) * 1000 + variant.versionCode
            def newApkName = "${getAppName()}-${variant.flavorName}-${variant.versionName}-${versionNumber}.apk"
            outputFileName = newApkName
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting file names produced from "Build APKs" for versionCode 1, versionName "1.0.0"  with armeabi-v7a and x86 ABIs respectively:

```
AppName-Prod-1.0.0-2001.apk
AppName-Prod-1.0.0-8001.apk
```

I couldn't find any doc yet on ABI names in the new setup. The old way to get them is obviously broken :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is already [addressed](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_api) and the answer is that it's not supported currently, but new API will be introduced for it.

Comment: I read the link, but I just wanted to know if there is a different way to achieve the same. If there is some other API which can help me achieve this task I would be happy to know about it.

Comment: Seems now the only right way for not very simple projects - just use old version and start to use new one once it get more mature

Comment: Currently doing the same.