# Could not set unknown property 'outputFileName' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Getting the error

> Could not set unknown property 'outputFileName' for object of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

using android studio 3.2.1

gradle 4.6

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
             variant.outputs.each { output ->
                 def fileName = "${project.name}_${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                 outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, fileName).getName()
             }
         }
```

Comment: you want change the release name?

Comment: no,I am just doing normal build which is failing

Answer (score 7):

you must use `all`

Use this code in your release biuld

```
android {
    //...
    buildTypes {

        debug {
        
        }
        release {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
                    def fileName = "${project.name}_${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                    outputFileName = fileName
                }
            }
        }
    }

} 
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got new error  --  Could not get unknown property 'baseName' for BuildType_Decorated{name=output, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.

Comment: @VatsalDesai you must call it in your release config check edited code

Comment: some explanation on why "all" works -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118506/3752244

Comment: The `variant.outputs.all { ` line should actually be `variant.outputs.all { output ->` in order to avoid the "unknown property" error. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @ChadSchultz you're right, thanks for edit and comment